# One dependency in multiple services classes with Dagger 2

Tags: java, dagger

I want to inject a custom class as an dependency in different service classes, but I don't get it work. It always ends with a NPE. Here is my example (simple Java SE) ...

My Main class to get everything running

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
            MyApplication MyApp = new MyApplication();
            MyApp.execute();
        }
    }
```

MyApplication class

```
public class MyApplication {

    private MyApplicationComponent appComponent;

    @Inject FooService fooService;
    @Inject BarService barService;
    @Inject BazService bazService;

    public MyApplication() {
        component = DaggerMyApplicationComponent.builder().build();
        component.inject(this);
    }

    public void execute() {
        fooService.doStuff();
        barService.doStuff();

        // this will happen in the FooService construct, see below        
        // bazService.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Component and Module classes as defined in Dagger, without using it the @Inject constructor way

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {MyApplicationModule.class})
public interface MyApplicationComponent {
    void inject(MyApplication application);
}

@Module
public class MyApplicationModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    FooService provideFooService() {
        return new FooService();
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    BarService provideBarService() {
        return new BarService();
    }

    @Provides
    BazService provideBazService() {
        return new BarService();
    }
}
```

Using the MyApplicationModule and MyApplicationComponent to provide needed dependencies works within the Main.class. I also want to use the BazService within the FooService class. Therefore I use the @Inject way to define it as a dependency with FooService.class.

Using @Inject of BazService within the FooService.class

```
public class FooService {
    @Inject BazService bazService;

    public FooService(){}

    public doStuff(){
        bazService.doStuff();
    }
}
```

Running the Main.class always ends within a NPE, due to undefined bazService in the FooSerivce class. I don't think, that I missed to add an annotation anywhere. I think Dagger will not work this way ... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

FooService expects bazService to be injected though field injection but you are calling bazService before this happens. If you want to call bazService.doStuff() in FooService's constructor you'll have to use constructor injection.

Comment: Thanks. You're right! I choose a bad example. I changed the last code block. The doStuff() within the FooService now calls the same method within the BazService. It works ... neither :/

Comment: Is it still throwing the NPE? The injection should be wprking fine now.